# Which is the .Net obfuscator with the best price/quality relation?

Tags: .net, security, obfuscation

I'm searching for a not so expensive .Net obfuscator and I'm not too smart in this field. 
A collegue suggest me to look for .Net Reactor. It has a good price but I'm not so sure about it.
In your experience and opinion ¿Which one is the best in terms of quality/price relation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337134/what-is-the-best-net-obfuscator-on-the-market

Comment: @Shoban: Sorry but I dont think the question you exposed is solving the problem of price/quality relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've been using [.NET Reactor](http://www.eziriz.com/) that makes a good job for $179.

Comment: Thanks, I believe this is going to be my choice.

Comment: I don't know how is your experience but eziriz is terrible in many ways. They don't give support (5 emails, no response in 5 months). Obfuscation causes many subtle bugs which causes app to crash in certain points, and even when it crashes you still can't get support.

Comment: Support is available here: http://groups.google.com/group/net-reactor-support but it is true that it is uneven. I've had problems with resources protected in assemblies and not accessible from the outside. Obfuscation problems arise depending on its level, as the more you protect some resources the more they are likely to be hidden from an external point of view.
Try to use the available presets and adjust settings according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out Babel Obfuscator which is free. Find it here:

http://code.google.com/p/babelobfuscator/

Answer (score 1):

Babel Obfuscator is affordable, reliable and offer a great support starting from 150 USD.